# C++ SAL.h errors in MSVC standard library

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, sal

MSVC and Clang-CL both report errors in the standard Visual C++ headers.
This must be a configuration error, as the standard headers are valid by default.
Errors shown (Non declared identifier, redifinition):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\vcruntime_new.h(47,26): error: unknown type name '_Post_writable_byte_size_'
_NODISCARD _Ret_notnull_ _Post_writable_byte_size_(_Size) _VCRT_ALLOCATOR
                         ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\vcruntime_new.h(47,58): error: expected ';' after top level declarator
_NODISCARD _Ret_notnull_ _Post_writable_byte_size_(_Size) _VCRT_ALLOCATOR
                                                         ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\vcruntime_new.h(52,54): error: unknown type name '_Post_writable_byte_size_'
_NODISCARD _Ret_maybenull_ _Success_(return != NULL) _Post_writable_byte_size_(_Size) _VCRT_ALLOCATOR
                                                     ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\vcruntime_new.h(52,86): error: expected ';' after top level declarator
_NODISCARD _Ret_maybenull_ _Success_(return != NULL) _Post_writable_byte_size_(_Size) _VCRT_ALLOCATOR
                                                                                     ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\vcruntime_new.h(58,26): error: unknown type name '_Post_writable_byte_size_'
_NODISCARD _Ret_notnull_ _Post_writable_byte_size_(_Size) _VCRT_ALLOCATOR
```

any many, many more...

The source of the errors are these SAL annotations:

```
_NODISCARD _Ret_maybenull_ _Success_(return != NULL) _Post_writable_byte_size_(_Size) _VCRT_ALLOCATOR
void* __CRTDECL operator new(
    size_t _Size,
    ::std::nothrow_t const&
    ) noexcept;

_NODISCARD _Ret_notnull_ _Post_writable_byte_size_(_Size) _VCRT_ALLOCATOR
void* __CRTDECL operator new[](
    size_t _Size
    );
```

In file C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h
any many more standard files.

My CMake Toolchain:

[image]

I've already tried reinstalling Visual Studio and all the compilers and SDKs, but nothing worked.
I've also searched for macros causing this but found nothing.
The program compiled file on Linux and MacOS and it compiled on my old Windows 10 too.
I've installed Windows 11 and installed the same Toolchains and now it does not work.

Comment: It is a macro, the compiler should never see it.  Look at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared\sal.h to see if the file is still intact and the #define is still there.  Use the /showIncludes compile option to verify that you get the expected sal.h included.

Comment: I already have checked all heathers, they are fine :(
IntelliSense also finds the SAL.h source and also the macros,
just the runtime compiler does not :/
And sal.h is included in all vc runtime headers, it makes no sence.

Comment: Can the issue be reproduced with a new simple program or is it specific to some existing code only? Maybe you have defines starting with underscore `_LIKE_THIS` (reserved for standard library implementation) that accidentally conflict with standard headers defines.

Comment: Are there header files calling each other and the two classes being member variables of each other? If so please avoid it.